# How to insert logo in header so that it's visible on first page only

Tags: microsoft-excel, headers

In excel if I insert image in the header on first page it shows up on all other pages as well. How can I make sure it only displays on the first page only?

Answer (score 1):

Check the "Different First Page" checkbox on the Design tab in the ribbon.

Also, please note there is a long-standing bug with Excel that stretches images in the header to an extra 10% of the original height.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a "Different First Page" header.

When you are editing the header on the first page, select the option **Different First Page** under Header & Footer Tools/Design in the menu bar.

If you want to add a header to the remaining pages, enter it on page 2 and it will be the same for all remaining pages.